# How to call a function from another window in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

assume I have 2 windows first being managestock and second being add design so the code of managestock loads a list from my sql server

here is the code of what I tried code for managestock-

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Test_app
{
    public partial class ManageStock : Window
    {

        DBAccess dBAccess = new DBAccess();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public ManageStock()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Clearlist();
            LoadList();
        }

        public void Clearlist()
        {
            dt.Clear();
            lstBox.ItemsSource = null;
            lstBox.Items.Clear();
        }
        public void LoadList()
        {
            Clearlist();
            string query = "select * from DesignTB";
            dBAccess.readDatathroughAdapter(query, dt);
            lstBox.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            dBAccess.closeConn();
        }
```

Code for add Design-

```
private void Upload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                int dsCode = Convert.ToInt32(Name_txt.Text);
                byte[] images = null;
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(imglocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader brs = new BinaryReader(stream);
                images = brs.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                SqlCommand insertCMD = new SqlCommand("insert into DesignTB(DesignCode,DesignIMG) values(@dsCode,@images)");
                insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dsCode", dsCode);
                insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@images", images);
                int row = dBAccess.executeQuery(insertCMD);
                if (row == 1)
                {
                    ManageStock ms = new ManageStock();
                    ms.LoadList();
                    Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to refresh the lstbox after the upload button is clicked how should I do it?

Comment: This really not how it works. You must use data binding and bind the ListBox to an the DataTable. When you bind the ListBox to a common data context of both windows the ListBox will update automatically. You must move the complete database and update logic and the data source to a separate class. Then create and instance of this class and assign the same instance to both DataContext properties of each window. Now each window can call the method of the *same* instance by referencing the DataContext.

Comment: Must? Technically, you don't absolutely have to use mvvm with Wpf. If you don't use mvvm then you are going to find people suggest you do so.

Comment: @Andy I'm not saying he must use MVVM. I'm not even mentioning MVVM. I said he must use data binding because he has to move the logic to the DataContext where he can't (shouldn't) directly reference the controls. Data binding is not MVVM.

Comment: You must operate on the same ManageStock instance that is already displaying. You can't create a new instance only to call a method. Usually you would wrap the db access into a dedicated globally shared class that exposes read and write API. This class naturally has full awareness of any changes that have been committed. Simply allow your ManageStock to observe this repository class for changes. That's the proper way. A "simpler" solution involves data binding as mentioned before where the database handling takes place in the same class that also exposes the data source for the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it didn't call 'ms.Show()'

```
if (row == 1)
{
    ManageStock ms = new ManageStock();
    ms.LoadList();
    Close();
}
```

I don't know the exact situation, but my answer is this.

If the ManageStock window is already active

```
private void Upload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // your code...

    // refresh all ManageStock Window
    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        if (window is ManageStock manageStock)
            manageStock.LoadList();
}
```

.NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: You should understand that the original code is the result of a very bad class design. Analogous to the principle that a class must not know the internals of another class, one Window must not know the layout of another Window. The only reason why the second window is calling LoadList() on the ManageStock window is because it knows the details of the ManageStock window. A general solution is tolet the first window observe the ManageStock window for changes to allow it to update itself. In this particular scenario the recommended solution would be to observe the database for changes instead.

Comment: Regarding my downvote: your solution, apart from introducing more bad design (because it is based on the current bad design) is that it simply won't work. You can't create a random instance, call its methods and close it afterwards. Let aside that the Window can only show the updated list when it is visible, you must operate on the same instance that is already existing. Unless the modified variables are static class variables the changes are instance related. Your solution generally doesn't work.